# upload files directly to amazon s3 using fineuploader

Tags: fine-uploader

I am trying upload files to directly to s3 but as per my research its need server side code or dependency on facebook,google etc. is there any way to upload files directly to amazon using fineuploder only?

Answer (score 2):

There are three ways to upload files directly to S3 using Fine Uploader:

1. Allow Fine Uploader S3 to send a small request to your server before each API call it makes to S3.  In this request, your server will respond with a signature that Fine Uploader needs to make the request.  This signatures ensures the integrity of the request, and requires you to use your secret key, which should not be exposed client-side.  This is discussed here: http://blog.fineuploader.com/2013/08/16/fine-uploader-s3-upload-directly-to-amazon-s3-from-your-browser/.
2. Ask Fine Uploader to sign all requests client-side.  This is a good option if you don't want Fine Uploader to make any requests to your server at all.  However, it is critical that you don't simply hardcode your AWS secret key.  Again, this key should be kept a secret.  By utilizing an identity provider such as Facebook, Google, or Amazon, you can request very limited and temporary credentials which are fed to Fine Uploader.  It then uses these credentials to submit requests to S3.  You can read more about this here: http://blog.fineuploader.com/2014/01/15/uploads-without-any-server-code/.
3. The third way to upload files directly to S3 using Fine Uploader is to either generate temporary security credentials yourself when you create a Fine Uploader instance, or simply hard-code them in your client-side code.  I would suggest you not hard-code security credentials.

Comment: Any idea why this might be happening? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52944027/react-fineuploaders3-calling-backend-signature-endpoint

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with fine uploader you can do.Here is a link that explains very well what you need to do http://blog.fineuploader.com/2013/08/16/fine-uploader-s3-upload-directly-to-amazon-s3-from-your-browser/

Comment: I can see there are examples with server side only and I am looking for only javascript based upload to s3. I am not sure how to add policy to request as in all examples they are using server side code. please help!!!

Comment: @KrishnaBhatt I have explained how to do this in my answer.  Also, the link provided by Burak explains in detail how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is  what you need. In this blogpost fineuploader team introduces serverless s3 upload via javascript. http://blog.fineuploader.com/2014/01/15/uploads-without-any-server-code/